# Perl send ajax response then exec()

Tags: ajax, perl, exec

Perl script needs to receive ajax request, send a "success" message back to browser, and then "spawn" a process to run in the background. (this spawned process could take 10 minutes to run, so I don't want the browser to wait for that - or for an apache timeout to occur)

I was under the impression that the Perl [exec()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) function would do this.  Better than using fork() or system() since those are supposed to wait for a response.

But, the script seems to be waiting for the exec() program to finish before sending the success message to the browser.  Here's the very end of my Perl script:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "success"; # this gets returned via ajax

exec $script_filename, $var1, $var2, $var3;
```

Everything works, but the browser isn't receiving the "success" message until $script_filename finishes running.

What I want to do seems similar to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434455/how-to-handle-long-ajax-requests-send-a-response-but-continue-to-work), but there aren't enough specifics there.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: fork() does not "wait for a response."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to another StackOverflow question which seems to solve my problem - see [Paul Tomblin's response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975466/should-i-disable-the-buffer-to-launch-a-background-process-in-a-cgi-program).

It seems that if the perl script does exec(), then apache waits.  But if the perl script first does a fork, and then the fork does the exec(), then everything works as expected.

And here's what it looks like in my code, replacing what was in my original post:

```
use POSIX 'setsid';

$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';

# This should flush stdout.
my $ofh = select(STDOUT);$| = 1;select $ofh;

my $kpid = fork;
if ($kpid)
{
    # Parent process
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "success"; # this gets returned via ajax
}
else
{
    close STDIN;
    close STDOUT;
    close STDERR;
    setsid();
    my $gpid = fork;
    if (!$gpid)
    {
        open(STDIN, "</dev/null") ;
        open(STDOUT, ">/dev/null") ;
        open(STDERR, ">/dev/null") ;
        # Child process
        exec($script_filename, $var1, $var2, $var3) ;
    }
    exit 0;
}
```

Thanks to Adam for confirming right away that what I was originally trying to do was flawed.

Thanks to Jonathan for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Congrats on the fix! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others can learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: I will.  It's making me wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Apache will wait for your script to finish before it completes the response to the browser. You should schedule a job to run in the background and then let your script terminate.

In order to schedule a background job you can either implement your background task processor as a daemon which accepts tasks via IPC (e.g. via a UNIX domain socket) from your perl script before executing them. Alternatively you can use existing UNIX tools for background job scheduling like `at` or `batch`. See [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) for details.

If you require very high reliability, you may also want to persist a task to external storage before confirming to the client that the task is scheduled.

Comment: +1 for 'Apache will wait' (but I'm not quite so sure about the rest).  Using `fork()` and having the child run the background process and the parent exit (so Apache stops waiting) will resolve the issue.  You don't have to use complex scheduling (`batch` or `at`); `fork()` is quite adequate.  It may well have advantages; the forked child has context that may simplify the setup for the background processing.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this: $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';

defined (my $kid = fork) or die "Cannot fork: $!\n";
if ($kid) {
    print "Parent has finished\n";
}
else {
    # do something time-consuming

}

Comment: @JonathanLeffler From the OP's code it seems the intention is to run an external command/script. This is easily accomplished with at/batch and ensures greater isolation (think signals, process group, file descriptors, etc). When the context from the parent script is needed, then `fork()` may have an advantage.

Comment: @egret Well, you should at least also close STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: File streams/descriptors are important (and should be redirected to /dev/null - rather than just closed).  There's no major problem if the child needs to execute another process.  It (the child before doing `exec`) can create its own process group if it wants to.  It can set its own signal handlers if it wants to; I'm not convinced there's any insuperable problem.  Equally, if the process is going to take 10 minutes to run, there isn't going to be any real efficiency issues with using `batch` or `at`.

Comment: I think I found an example with the specifics I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975466/should-i-disable-the-buffer-to-launch-a-background-process-in-a-cgi-program -- I'm experimenting with this now.  Adam, Jonathan: a million thanks for responding to my post so quickly.

Comment: Yes, the standard file descriptors should be redirected rather than closed.